# What is the equivalent of Cocoa's NSRange struct on Android (Java)?

Tags: java, android, ios, cocoa

What is the equivalent of Cocoa's **`NSRange`** struct on Android?

```
typedef struct _NSRange {
    NSUInteger location;
    NSUInteger length;
} NSRange;
```

I'm trying to find java class for that but I cannot find anything.

Answer (score 2):

you can use a java class like that :

```
class JavaNSRange {
    public Integer location;
    public Integer length;
}
```

NSInteger ==> Integer